# javascript - format xxx-xxxx for match() function

Tags: javascript, html, format, match

I want to use `str.match(xxx-xxxx);` but don't know what syntax to use. can someone help me out i want something like `/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/`

Thanks.

Comment: What would you like to match and which syntax don't you get ?

Comment: Please be more specific so we don't vote you down.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "123-1234";
var isMatch = (str.match(/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/)!==null);
```

isMatch equals true.

```
var str = "1223-1234";
var isMatch = (str.match(/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/)!==null);
```

isMatch equals false.

```
var str = "1223-134";
var isMatch = (str.match(/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/)!==null);
```

isMatch equals false.

```
var str = "000-1122";
var isMatch = (str.match(/^\d{3}-\d{4}$/)!==null);
```

isMatch equals true.

http://jsfiddle.net/y279u/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
str.match(/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/)
```

Read more on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match